# Compare data of two columns of one dataframe with two columns of another dataframe and find mismatch data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe `df1` as following-

[image: first dataframe]

Second dataframe `df2` is as following-

[image: second dataframe]

and I want the resulted dataframe as following

[image: final dataframe]

Dataframe df1 & df2 contains a large number of columns and data but here I am showing sample data. My goal is to compare Customer and ID column of df1 with Customer and Part Number of df2. Comparison is to find mismatch of data of df1['Customer'] and df1['ID'] with df2['Customer'] and df2['Part Number']. Finally storing mismatch data in another dataframe `df3`. For example: Customer(rishab) with ID(89ab) is present in df1 but not in `df2`.Thus Customer, Order#, and Part are stored in `df3`.

I am using `isin()` method to find mismatch of `df1` with `df2` for one column only but not able to do it for comparison of two columns.

```
df3 = df1[~df1['ID'].isin(df2['Part Number'].values)]


#here I am only able to find mismatch based upon only 1  column ID but I want to include Customer also
```

I can use loop also but the data is very large(Time complexity will increase) and I am sure there can be one-liner code to achieve this task. I have also tried to use merge but not able to produce the exact output.

So, how to produce this exact output? I am also not able to use `isin()` for two columns and I think `isin()` cannot to use for two columns

Comment: This is a lot easier to answer if you provide example data in a way that can be easily imported, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: @Wouter sure... I will edit with reproducible pandas example. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on = ['Customer', 'ID'],right_on= ['Customer', 'Part Number'],  how='left', indicator=True)
df3.reset_index(inplace = True)
df3 = df3[df3['_merge'] == 'left_only']
```

Here, you first do a `left join` on the columns, and put `indicator = True`, which will give another column like _merge, which has indicator mentioning which side the data exists, and then we pick `left_only` from those.

Comment: can you suggest please why df_3 is used here. I think it must be df3 in last line

Comment: Yes it should be that, thanks, will just update it

Answer (score 0):

You can try outer join to get non matching rows. Something like `df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on = ['Customer', 'ID'],right_on= ['Customer', 'Part Number'],  how = "outer")`

Comment: thanks for your answer. this will also consider data of second dataframe df2. But I want mismatch of df1 only in df3. df2 dataframe is very lat=rge and approximately contains 50000 rows

Comment: Can you please suggest code which will only consider 1st dataframe mismatch with second dataframe

Comment: Can you try this `df3 = df1.where((df1.Customer!=df2.Customer) & (df1.ID!=df2.PartNumber))`

Comment: sure I will try... but don't know which solution will produce final exact result. Thanks for your answer